# How can i wrap line on white spaces first and then at any other character for Windows Outlook?

Tags: html, windows, outlook

I have an email utility tool which takes input such as a custom template file and "To" email address. It reads the custom template file and then convert it into an HTML with some CSS for dynamic rendering, ultimately sending the email to the "To" email address.

I want to wrap lines inside a table such that first it gets wrap at white spaces and if not possible then move to any other character.

For this i am using word-wrap: break-word. This is working fine in Outlook client on mac machines but Outlook client in Windows is not redering the content properly. The option word-wrap: break-all is working fine for both of them but it breaks the line at random char, does not look for white spaces first.